# Android: Draw image on Camera Preview

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent

I want to create a Camera application that draws an image on the camera preview. When the camera is running I want to add an image file (example : image.png) on the camera preview.
Here is the code that I have to run the camera, but I don't know the code that adds/draws the image.png

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
"IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

try {
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't overlay items on the camera, unless the camera preview is in your app itself. Using the intent won't allow you to do this.

One of the example apps from my book, Pro Android Augmented Reality, shows you how to do this. You can find the open source code for that app [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality/tree/master/Pro%20Android%20AR%203%20Widget%20Overlay).

Essentially, you must use a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) to display the camera data, and then use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) or [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to draw things on top of it.

Comment: If use SurfaceView to display the camera, the display is like as ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE or depent on the layout?

Comment: You handle all the displaying etc. It's completely unrelated to Intents.

Comment: but is it possible, right? do you have an example app using SurfaceView that the display like as ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE ?

Comment: the display like as ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.

Comment: If you add buttons to your layout that take photos and do the other things, then yes

Comment: @RaghavSood Can we capture video with overlay items on the camera?
Example: our video will contain overlay items and video's data content also.