# Drawing on camera preview android

Tags: android, camera, drawing

I'm recording video and simultaneously want to draw something on camera preview such that recorded video will record activities done on camera preview(draw). I searched lot about this didn't find any proper solution.I also want to do following work

1. Face detection and apply some change on that like change hair colour.
2. change preview background custom
3. brightness and contrast on camera preview.

Comment: @chintankhetiya Thanks But I don't see any drawing features in the sample code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689095/android-draw-image-on-camera-preview

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689194/192373) by [Raghav Sood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) don't resolve your problem. That's because the camera preview (via SurfaceView) cannot be synchronized with your image processing, which probably relies on `onPreviewFrame()` callbacks.

To achieve the desired effect, you must hide the preview (probably, using the SurfaceTexture instead of SurfaceView), and display the preview images (as received in `onPreviewFrame()`), with the corresponding overlays, or maybe modify the image and display the result, in your own view. For best results, you will probably use OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Can u please elaborate how to do this?

Comment: One example is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216893/android-camera-asynctask-with-preview-callback; an OpenGL example can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519235/modifying-camera-output-using-surfacetexture-and-opengl